# How to recognize a wifi connection is a hotspot connection (hotspot using cellular signal) in Android?

Tags: android, wifi, cellular-network, hotspot

As the title describes, I am developing android application, and I want to know whether the current WIFI connection is a hotspot connection. If so, I will pause the download process so that the cellular data will not be wasted. I did not find any official APIs that can do this functionality. So I wonder if anyone has done something about it?

Answer (score 0):

The `ConnectivityManager` method [isActiveNetworkMetered()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#isActiveNetworkMetered()) (or the equivalent [ConnectivityManagerCompat.isActiveNetworkMetered()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/net/ConnectivityManagerCompat.html#isActiveNetworkMetered(android.net.ConnectivityManager)) if you need to support devices less than API 16) tells you exactly when a network is metered. A WiFi hotspot will be a metered connection.

Comment: This method is supported on API 16 and higher, right? Is there any other way for API lower than 16?

Comment: @Mike - the Compat method listed works back to API 9, although prior to API 16 there is no separate 'metered' status so it is only checking for wifi prior to API 16.

Comment: OK, Thanks a lot.